# Error in maven clean install in intellij. I tried everything possible, but I am not understanding why this error comes on jenkins build

Tags: java, intellij-14

I am getting build error. I tried installing a newer version on intellij, but still getting the same error. Not understanding what is happening.I am ruuning intellij 2022.3.1. and this is a maven project.
the line  "at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext"
has been repeated 500 times.

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:161)
        at org.fusesource.jansi.Ansi.isEnabled(Ansi.java:172)
        at org.fusesource.jansi.Ansi.ansi(Ansi.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.logging.AnsiMessageBuilder.<init>`(AnsiMessageBuilder.java:45)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.logging.MessageUtils.level(MessageUtils.java:163)
        at org.slf4j.impl.MavenSimpleLogger.renderLevel(MavenSimpleLogger.java:50)
        at org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger.log(SimpleLogger.java:277)
        at org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger.info(SimpleLogger.java:480)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.logging.Slf4jLogger.info(Slf4jLogger.java:59)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:464)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
```